# No sound after suspend/standby

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

For some reason I don't have any sound after suspend/standby on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

It happens on a XMG C504, and the online solutions do NOT work.

According to alsamixer the 0 is a Intel Haswell HMDI and the 1 is a Realtek ALC282

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7414000 irq 53
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7410000 irq 52

lspci | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05) 

lsmod | grep -q snd_hda_intel
lsmod | grep -q snd_foo
```

return no result

This does not work

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Or this

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

--- EDIT ---

The most funny thing is, if I play something, putt the volume wide open and then mute it it plays for a fraction of a second, this only happens when muting not when unmuting.

--- EDIT ---

Another strange thing, sound over HMDI does work after suspend/standby... switching back to the speakers doesn't... even after repeatedly switching between HDMI and speakers...

--- EDIT ---

To help as much people as possible, the following systems seem to be affected by this bug, all based on the Realtek ALC282;

- XMG C504 (Based on the Gigabyte P35 series)
- Gigabyte P35w v2
- Gigabyte P35x v4

As provided by @NeverMinded

The bug has been reported : 
[bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1366241) and [bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49421)

Comment: Same thing happens on me

Comment: Finally! Someone with the same issue! I did find out that Windows does have the same problem but not all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on Kubuntu 15.04, Realtek ALC282.

Here is a workaround:

1. Suspend/resume: no sound threw the speaker
2. Mute the audio with the keyboard (no GUI) : Fn + Mute
3. Increase the audio  with the keyboard (no GUI) : Fn + VolumeUp
4. Sound is back!

The bug has been reported : 
[bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1366241) and [bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49421)